# Add static column to Dynamic LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

In my project, I'm using Dynaic LINQ (https://dynamic-linq.net/) to select data from a database. Here's my current select code:

```cs
List<dynamic> clientData = await clientDataset
    .Select($"new({string.Join(",", requiredColumns)})")
    .ToDynamicListAsync();
```

I need to extend this. In a later step on the client side, I have to add additional properties to the clientData objects. As far as I know, this is not possible out of the box. The following approach doesn't work:

```cs
foreach (dynamic listEntry in clientData)
{
    listEntry["MyAdditionalProp1"] = GetStringValue1();
    listEntry["MyAdditionalProp2"] = GetStringValue2();
}
```

So I had the idea to add those as fake columns in the select statement, which doesn't work also.

```cs
List<dynamic> clientData = await clientDataset
    .Select($"new({string.Join(",", requiredColumns)},'' AS MyAdditionalProp1, '' AS MyAdditionalProp2)")
    .ToDynamicListAsync();
```

The names of the additional properties (MyAdditionalProp1, MyAdditionalProp1, ...) are known before the select, but they are dynamic, so I can't hard-code them.

How can I add dynamic properties to my list and modify their values atrwards like in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since Dynamic LINQ creates an anonymous type at runtime based on the `string` new expression, you can't add properties to the object once created.

So you do need to add the properties to the new expression:

```
List<dynamic> clientData = await clientDataset
    .Select($"new({string.Join(",", requiredColumns)},\"\" AS MyAdditionalProp1, \"\" AS MyAdditionalProp2)")
    .ToDynamicListAsync();
```

Then, since you don't know the property names at runtime, you must use the helper functions provided by the library:

```
foreach (dynamic listEntry in clientData) {
    listEntry.SetDynamicPropertyValue("MyAdditionalProp1", GetStringValue1());
    listEntry.SetDynamicPropertyValue("MyAdditionalProp2", GetStringValue2());
}
```

And you can access the property values with `GetDynamicPropertyValue()`.

NOTE: Extensive use of `dynamic` can cause performance issues.